# Vector iterator override operator ->

Tags: c++

I have for homework to make my own abstract class Vector. This vector should have iterator. I make iterator in public part of the Vector. This is my code for iterator:

```
class iterator {
    friend class Vector;
    Vector* v_;
    int position_;

    iterator(Vector* v,int position)
    : v_(v),
      position_(position)
    {}

public:

    iterator()
    : v_(0),
      position_(0)
    {}

    iterator& operator++() {// pre
        position_++;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator operator++(int) {//post
        iterator res=*this;
        position_++;
        return res;
    }

    T& operator*() {
        return v_->buffer_[position_];
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return &buffer_[position_];
    }

    bool operator==(const iterator& other) const {
        return position_ == other.position_;
    }

    bool operator!=(const iterator& other) const {
        return !operator==(other);
    }
};
```

My question is if the operator -> is correct defined.

Thanks

Comment: Given that it won't compile as written, it's obviously not correct (there is no `buffer_` in scope when you use it in the definition of `operator->`; perhaps you mean `v_->buffer_`?)

Comment: Want to know your code is correct? Try it! Make a small test program that uses it and see if it gives you the expected results.

Comment: This is only part of the code :)

Comment: It is generally more useful if you are able to show us your code together with a small test that fails, than just giving us a class and telling us to play "spot the error".

Comment: i guess the main point is that you have to write &(buffer_[position_]) or simply (buffer_ + position_) i mean if there is any problem to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're really wanting a slightly modified definition that gets the value at the current position of the vector, i.e., `return &((*v_)[position_]);` if you've overloaded the `operator[]` of your vector class.  Otherwise in order to get access to the `buffer_` of your vector, you have to dereference the vector first in order to get to the buffer, i.e., `return &(v_->buffer[position_]);`